# In numpy array how is dimension changed when slicing? Explain the following code

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

In the following code, the transpose works.

```
b = numpy.arange(4,3)
print(b[1:3,-1:)
print(b[1:3,-1:].shape)
print(b[1:3,-1:].T)
print(b[1:3,-1:].T.shape)
```

In the following case, transpose does not.

```
b = numpy.arange(4,3)
print(b[1:3,-1)
print(b[1:3,-1].shape)
print(b[1:3,-1].T)
print(b[1:3,-1].T.shape)
```

Comment: It would be nice (as a in more polite) if you showed some of the results, even the error (or other wise show how the transpose does not work).  Experience coders can guess or even test your code, but not everyone has that option.

Comment: The server I practice python on does not have browser. The terminal I use to post the question does not have python. I am not intentionally missing out on reporting the output.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing a numpy array behaves differently depending on whether you slice with a range or a scalar. Your first example slices with a range, so although it ends up with the second dimension only having size 1, that dimension remains. Your second example slices with a scalar, and in that case the appropriate dimension is collapsed. So in the second example, you are left with a one-dimensional array, which doesn't do anything under transpose - it doesn't have any other dimensions to swap around.

Comment: 1D arrays support transpose just fine - it just happens that your expectation for transpose (swap last two axes) matches numpys (reverse all axes) only when ndim==2.

Comment: @Eric true - I was running off memory and assumed it failed due to the question. Updated